# Variant of the Brachistochrone

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

I am pretty confident I understand how to use Variational Calculus in order to find out the path between two points on which a bead could slide under gravity in the shortest time. If starting from $(0,0)$, the path is described by $$x(\phi) = a(\phi-\sin(\phi))$$ $$y(\phi) = a(\cos{\phi}-1)$$

But my problem is when determining the exact fastest path between a point and a given line. For example, if the initial point is $A = (0,0)$ and I want the fastest path from $A$ to line $x=1$, I don't know which brachistochrone curve should I choose. I have tried to use Lagrange multipliers, but I couldn't come to anything meaningful.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No. Give the formula above, the time to slide for a bead would be $\sqrt{\frac{a}{g}} \cdot \phi_1$, where $\phi_1$ is where $x$ becomes 1. Thus, it is a question of finding a minimum of $a\cdot\phi_1^2$.

Comment: I think that the solution is $\:\phi_{1}=\pi\:$ and then $\:\alpha=1/\pi\:$ or in  general $\:\alpha=x_{0}/\pi\:$  if you want the line $\:x=x_{0}\:$ instead of  $\:x=1\:$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The answer is $\:\phi_{1}=\pi\:$ and $\:\alpha=1/\pi$.

---

[image]

Minima at : $\phi = (2k+1)\pi,\quad k=0,1,2,3\cdots\:$.

Turning points where :  $\tan\left(\dfrac{\phi}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\phi}{2}\:$.

[image]